# Finding out the symmetric difference between two sets (general formula)

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

Working on a question looking for:

Pr(A △ B), the solutions manual indicates this is

Pr (A △ B) = Pr(A) + Pr(B) - 2*Pr(A and B)

This reminds me of the inclusion exclusion formula for:

Pr(A or B) = Pr(A) + Pr(B) - Pr(A and B)

Where the reasoning for the subtraction is we remove the quantities we have "counted" twice i.e. the overlapping region between A and B.

Similarly, what is a good analogy to think of when subtracting 2*Pr(A and B) in the symmetric difference formula above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Similarly, what is a good analogy to think of when subtracting $2*\operatorname{Pr}(A \cap B)$ in the symmetric difference formula above?

You can write the two relations as:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat}{2}
\operatorname{Pr}(A \cup B) & =\big(\operatorname{Pr}(A)-\operatorname{Pr}(A \cap B)\big)\;+\; \operatorname{Pr}(A \cap B) & \;+\;\big(\operatorname{Pr}(B)-\operatorname{Pr}(A \cap B)\big) \\
\operatorname{Pr}(A \Delta B) & =\big(\operatorname{Pr}(A)-\operatorname{Pr}(A \cap B)\big)\; & +\;\big(\operatorname{Pr}(B)-\operatorname{Pr}(A \cap B)\big) \\
\end{alignat}
\end{cases}
$$

That makes it more clear that $\operatorname{Pr}(A \Delta B)$ counts only the elements which belong to ***exactly*** one of the sets, as compared to the union $\operatorname{Pr}(A \cup B)$ which counts elements belonging to ***at least*** one.

Comment: Thank you that helps clarify which regions Pr (A △ B) is counting.